# What is the exact medical evidence which UDCA might worsen the symptom of gastric ulcer patient?

Tags: stimulants, ulcers

In South Korea and Japan, the FDA label of UDCA (Ursodeoxycholic acid) says 'UDCA might worsen the symptom of gastric ulcer patient because UDCA stimulates mucous membrane. Therefore, gastric ulcer patient should avoid taking UDCA as contraindication.'

Fortunately, I've found this information and recommended my patient to stop taking UDCA from now on. 
She is 57 years old and doesn't have bad habits for digestive organs and taking PPI to restore damaged mucous membrane of stomach.

I tried to find the medical evidence which UDCA stimulates mucous membrane but seems complicated.

Can somebody advise me here?

Or is it just because UDCA is a kind of acid? (Ursodeoxycholic acid)

Thank you !

Comment: A quick review of the literature seems to indicate it's rather the opposite, so I can understand why you're asking.

Comment: @CareyGregory, As I wrote, FDA label of some countries even Japan are warning the usage with gastric ulcer patients. I also inquired to the big manufacturer and waiting because they gave me a word to provide a feedback once they find enough answer.